# Echo not showing

Tags: php, mysql

On my login page, if someone logs in with the correct detials they go to my main.php and if they don't have the correct details they should get shown an error message, but instead it goes to a blank screen!

Tried to figure this out for ages

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
session_start(); // Starting Session
include("connect.php");
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
if ($username == "") {
echo "Username field is empty!"; 
header("Location: incorrectlogin.php");
}else{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "game");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysqli_select_db($con,"game");
$query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from users where password='$password' AND     username='$username'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; 
header("location: main.php"); 
} else {
echo "That username or password is incorrect";
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
}
}
```

It might just be me but it looks like it SHOULD work, any ideas?

Comment: Where is the `if`? And the code before it. Do you start a session?

Comment: Showing a blank screen can often mean you have a syntax error in PHP. You also didn't provide us enough code for us to debug. Show us a complete snippet. Where is your starting `if`? Where is the closing `}`?

Comment: ^^^ _Always_ when developing code, make sure PHP is displaying errors on screen. At the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Put an exit();after header row.Also have you enabled `session_start()`?

Comment: Added the session code. @Michael I already have that and there is no error :(

Comment: It appears from here that you're missing a closing `}` on your `else` condition.

Comment: Session start is right at the start of the code, the exit(); didn't work :(

Comment: @JayBlanchard the } is there, I just didn't put it in the code lol

Comment: @RyanMcKenna the error reporting runtime code needs to be way at the top - a blank screen in PHP when output is otherwise expected generally indicates a fatal error, which display_errors will show - Look also in your web server's error log, where a fatal error will be detailed.

Comment: post complete code..!

Comment: Ah!  Take out the `or die(mysqli_error())` after `mysqli_num_rows()`.  A return of 0 rows will be falsy, and trigger that die() but no error will show because _there is no error_.  Do not add `or die(...)` after every database call, only those which can actually trigger an error state (like `mysqli_connect(), mysqli_query()`)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Not only do the display_errors not show anything, neither does the error logs

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That worked! I would have NEVER have found that, thanks!

Comment: Can you post the answer as an answer so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem resides here in the error handling (ironically) added to `mysqli_num_rows()`:

```
 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

When `mysqli_num_rows()` returns `0` (no rows found), the `or die()` is triggered here. Since there was no error, you get no output from `mysqli_error()`.

But *zero rows returned* is not an error state so it is not appropriate to add error handling to it.  You are already handling the row count returned subsequently with:

```
if ($rows == 1) {
  // etc...
}
```

...so you can safely remove the `or die(...)`.  It would be more appropriate to use that error handling expression on the previous call to `mysqli_query()`, where an error can actually occur if the SQL string is invalid.

I also would be remiss if I didn't mention the issue of storing user passwords in plain text, as this implies:

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
```

I recommend reviewing [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) for truly excellent examples on how to improve the security of your password storage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `if` statement , can u paste the whole code (or) few lines above and below of the above line s of code